# Can not make a timer with while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, timer, logic, settimeout

I am trying to create a timer with while loops and setTimeout but everytime i give an input the code crashes. İ thought doing it this way would work but seems like it doesnt. What is the problem here? And how do i achieve what i want with while loop and setTimeout?

```
function countdown(durationInput) {

while (durationInput > 0) {

    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(durationInput)
        durationInput = durationInput - 1
        console.log(durationInput)
    }, 1000)
}
}
```

Comment: The `while` loop attempts to create an infinite number of timers. `durationInput` would never decrease until a timer completes. `setTimeout()` does not pause code execution, instead, it schedules a function for later execution.

Comment: Remove while loop. Put condition if (durationInput > 0) { contDown(durationInput); } after the last.console.log and hope that you won't get stack overflow for a large value of durationInput.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Well look at this image. What you see is the basics of how javascript works.

JS is single threaded. That means 1 core do the work. Thats the event loop.

The event loop grabs the event from the callback queue and put its on the call stack and executes it.

If you run `setTimeout` you put it into the callback que

The problem: When the event loop is blocked by an synchronouse task like your `while` loop, that means the event loop cannot grab the events to the stack, because its blocked.

What happens is: The while loop runs and runs and adds more and more `setTimeout` events to the callback que until the programm crashes.

1 possible solution could be to use promises:

```
async function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(res => {
      setTimeout(res, ms)
   })
}
```

```js
async function sleep(ms) {
   return new Promise(res => {
       setTimeout(res, ms)
   })
}

async function main() {


console.log("waiting 5 seconds without blocking the main thread")
await sleep(5000)

console.log("done")


}


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are generating an infinite loop, as the `durationInput` doesn't update until the `setTimeout` executes. And you are filling the execution stack with a huge cue.

For fixing it, you need to create a variable that will store the initial value of the `durationInput` and subtract from duration in the while loop.

```js
function countdown(duration, intervalInSeconds = 1) {
  let count = duration;

  while (duration > 0) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(count--);
    }, intervalInSeconds * 1000);
    duration--;
  }
}

countdown(10);
```